# Roslaunch XML boolean operators

Tags: roslaunch, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently using a conditional line in a roslaunch file as shown below:

```
<arg name="cond1" value="true"/>
<node pkg="PKG" type="TYPE" name="NAME" unless="$(arg cond1)">
...
```

However I wish to have this node not load if EITHER cond1 or cond2 is set.  No combination of

```
<arg name="cond2" value="false"/>
unless="$(arg cond1 or cond2)"
unless="$(arg cond1) or $(arg cond2)"
```

seems to work, returning the error:

```
$(arg var) may only specify one arg
```

How do I use boolean operators (AND or OR) in the roslaunch XML syntax?

Many thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51525/roslaunch-xml-boolean-operators/) by [Arrakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2996/arrakis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2013-01-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the only way to do that is construct another arg that represents the condition you want using the unless/if attribute to create it.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The above suggestion will work, as well as the following.  However both seem like hacks to me and I would love to hear if anyone knows of if/when proper boolean operators will be added to the roslaunch XML syntax

```
<group unless="$(arg cond1)">
    <node pkg="PKG" type="TYPE" name="NAME" unless="$(arg cond2)" />
</group>
```

---

Originally posted by [Arrakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2996/arrakis/) with karma: 163 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-01-07**:
Thanks for adding a code snippet - that pretty much what I had in mind for making an arg. There's a roslaunch SIG (http://www.ros.org/wiki/hydro/Planning/roslaunch) for hydro which might be a good place to bring this up.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Adding this because I couldn't easily find it anywhere:

> ```
>     <arg name="foo" default="false" />
> ```

```
    <group if="$(arg foo)">
        <!--do some stuff-->
    </group>
    <group unless="$(arg foo)">
        <!--do some different stuff-->
    </group>
```

---

Originally posted by [AMatt](https://answers.ros.org/users/27753/amatt/) with karma: 11 on 2017-02-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2021-02-10**:
Here's [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44002394/6010333) if anyone's needs it

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `eval` keyword if you are using ROS Kinetic or newer version. See [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML).

This is a very neat solution for boolean operators in roslaunch file. An example for an "or" operation:

```
<arg name="cond_1" default="false"/> 
<arg name="cond_2" default="false"/>
<node pkg="PKG" type="TYPE" name="NAME" if="$(eval arg('cond_1) or arg('cond_2'))" />
```

This syntax can of course also be applied to including a launch file.

Thanks to @gvhoorn's:
`$(eval <expression>)` allows to evaluate arbitrary complex python expressions.

---

Originally posted by [Maverobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/31254/maverobot/) with karma: 66 on 2018-01-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-24**:
This is neat, but note it's really almost arbitrary Python you can use in `eval`. It's not custom expressions in there.